# WiX: InstallUISequence + custom action

Tags: wix

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="myActionid"
          Before="ExecuteAction">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

i use this to set when my customAction will run but it doesent seem to run when i want it to.
in verbrose log i see this

*

*

[image]

My action runs too soon i need it to run right before Execute action (or between the middle bold part and executeaction)

because after that the properties change and i cant get the right values

alternatively make the properties stop from changing that would also work.

the properties are copies of `INSTALLDIR` meaning i've copied `BrowseDlg` and made the installdir dialog into a dialog that asks for three paths i need for my program. i will post that code too if you think its necessary but it feels like i could be able to just specify when my custom action runs to get the right values!

thank you for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i still dont know how to set mycustomAction to the specific runtime that i wanted but i dont need to anymore because i found out why my Properties like the `INSTALLDIR` was changed by `costfinalize`

i dont know the reason why it works this way but i had my directories with small letters in the id and then `costfinalize` changed them back to the default after the install sequence

so having all caps like this

```
<Directory Id="SPCSFOR" Name="Företag">
</Directory>
<Directory Id="SPCSGEM" Name="Gemensamma filer">
</Directory>
<Directory Id="VISMAADMIN" Name="SPCS Administration">
</Directory>
```

was the last piece of making my own `InstallDirDlg` working more like the original and the properties stays the way the user changes them with `BrowseDlg`

and after that it was easy for my to just set mycustomAction

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="myActionid"
          After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

like that and read the properties from there instead and no problems trying to time it just right to get the values i wanted!